# salesforce trailhead TOPIC: Input Data Using Forms

Tags: visualforce, trailhead

I am new to salesforce platform i am solving Trailhead salesforce.i got struck in Visualforce basics. ssuggest me to solve this error

REF:https://trailhead.salesforce.com/visualforce_fundamentals/visualforce_forms

**TRAILHEAD ERROR:Challenge Not yet complete... here's what's wrong:
The page component does not include the Contact Standard Controller.**

ERROR IN DEVELOPER VISUALFORCE CONSOLE: **Contacts does not exist**

CODE I HAD WRITTEN :

```
<apex:page standardController="Contacts">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{! Contact.First Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField  value="{! Contact.Last Name}"/>
        <apex:inputField  value = "{! Contact.Email}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{! save}" value="save"/>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

Thanks and Regards
sainath

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contacts is the Plural of the Contact object and is used in relationships between standard objects and Contact (i.e. Account.**Contacts**)

Change your code to use the correct API Name of the object `Contact`

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:inputField value="{!Contact.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:inputField  value="{!Contact.LastName}"/>
        <apex:inputField  value = "{!Contact.Email}"/>
        <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save"/>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```